# Why can't class-wide upper-bound constraints be covariant and lower-bound constraints be contravariant in Hack?

Tags: covariance, contravariance, type-constraints, hacklang

Regardless of the variance of parameter on the left side, the constraints placed on `Ta` and `Tb` in the following declaration fail the typecheck:

```php
class A<+TCov, -TCon, [±]Ta as TCov, [±]Tb super TCon> {
  public function __construct(private Ta $ta, private Tb $tb) {}
  // [various methods making use of Ta and Tb]
}
```

It's worth noting that the empty class declaration doesn't raise errors, but once the constrained parameters are *used* (in otherwise valid positions given their own variances), the typechecker raises one of the following:

> Illegal use of covariant type parameter (Typing[4120])... `as` constraints are contravariant
>
> Illegal use of contravariant type parameter (Typing[4121])... `super` constraints are covariant

with reference to the parameter on the right side of the constraint.

I can more understand why generic methods pose problems. The violating positions are fairly obvious, and using the arguments in positions matching the variance of their constraints are impossible:

```php
class A<+TCov, -TCon> {
  public function cov_violate<T as TCov>(T $v): void {
    // T can be cast to TCov and violate type if the original type is a subtype of T
  }
  public function con_violate<T super TCon>(): T {
    // vice versa for the contravariant parameter
  }

  public function cov_impossible<T as TCov>(): T {
    // how will we produce a T-typed value?
  }
  public function con_impossible<T super TCov>(T $v): void {
    // what will we do with a T-typed value?
  }
}
```

But what is the problem with class-wide parameters? For all six errant relationships (`{+|-| }T as +TCov` and `{+|-| }T super -TCon`) I can't think up a scenario where these wouldn't be type-safe. In my mind, their variances seem to either restrict their casting direction or their positions sufficiently to let declaring these relationships be safe.

Answer (score 0):

I was running 3.13.1 at the time of this question, but luckily the restriction has been relaxed to allow this subtyping of class type parameters as of HHVM 3.14.4 by [this commit](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/commit/7f14eab233a76f5183b83a51142082785a67a1d2)! The commit also points to [this Microsoft paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/variance-and-generalized-constraints-for-c-generics/) for a proof of soundness.